# Update the missing incremental number in a data set

Tags: plsql, sql-update

In one of my tables I have a column called 'Priority' which is a number starting from 1. With new data the next number will be added to the new record.
When I deleted a data from the middle there will be a gap in priority. I want to run a plsql update statement so that the mising numbers will be replaced according the priority order that I had before.

original data

```
Priority | user 
1        | A
2        | B
3        | C
4        | D
```

Then I delete the record B

```
Priority | user
1        | A
3        | C
4        | D
```

After Update it should be like

```
Priority | user
1        | A
2        | C
3        | D
```

Comment: Why? This seems like a lot of updating for no effective gain. Ordering the sequence 1,2,3 and the sequence 1,3,4 will produce the exact same results (at least for all other columns) in the exact same sequence.

Comment: Your point is correct. But I am showing this in client and I want it to be a continues number for the user to understand it.

Comment: Contrary to what many in IT think users have a tremendous ability to understand such things. You will find most deal with non-sequential lists all the time. But if you must present sequentially  consider creating a view the displays the ordinal values (1st,2nd,3rd ... ) but the under lying table having the underlying cardinal numbers (1,3,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without PL/SQL:

```
create table demo
( priority  number, username varchar2(20) );

insert all
    into demo values (2, 'A')
    into demo values (4, 'B')
    into demo values (9, 'C')
    into demo values (10, 'D')
select * from dual;

merge into demo o
using ( select row_number() over (order by priority) as new_priority
             , rowid as row_id
        from   demo ) n
on (n.row_id = o.rowid)
when matched then update set o.priority = n.new_priority;

select * from demo;

  PRIORITY USERNAME
---------- --------------------
         1 A
         2 B
         3 C
         4 D
```